# dropdown menu populated with db contents

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want all the instances of `Venue` be available as options in a dropdown menu inside a `new` form.
Here is a sketch inside event/new.html.erb , an `event` has one `venue`

```
  <%= f.select_tag(
    "venue",
    options_from_collection_for_select(Venue.all, "id", "name")
  ) -%>
```

another big question, what to put inside the `new` definition of the event controller?

Comment: Can you be more detail about the problem you are facing?

Comment: right now the error is `undefined method 'select_tag' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder` and I generally have no idea what I'm doing. I can't tell if this is a right way to use options_from_... inside <%= -%>, I don't know what should go in the `event` controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using a form like

```
<%= form_for @venue do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

you can use `f.select` instead of `f.select_tag`. There is no such thing as `f.select_tag`

```
<%= f.select(
  "venue",
  options_from_collection_for_select(Venue.all, "id", "name")
) -%>
```

Comment: perfect, page loads, dropdown is populated. thank you!